# constraints in grails

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-domain-class, grails-controller, grails-constraints

Hi I am having some trouble getting my constraints to work in my grails project. I am trying to just make sure that the field for Site_ID is not left blank but it still accepts an blank input. Also I am trying to set the order in which the fields appear but even that is not reflecting on the page when I try it out. Here is the code:

```
package translation

class J2_Translations {

    String Site_ID 
    String I18NKey

    static constraints = {
        Site_ID(blank:false) 
        I18NKey()
    }
}
```

and here is my code for the controller, I am not doing anything special I just want the constraints to work

```
package translation

class J2_TranslationsController {

    def scaffold = J2_Translations
}
```

thanks,
Ameya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails is a convention-over-configuration framework.  Make sure you follow the standard Java naming conventions.  Properties should be named with camel-case identifiers with the leading character in lowercase.  For example:

```
String siteId
String i18nKey
```

Comment: Are you saying constraints won't work unless property names are camel cased?

Comment: Yes.  It's (arguably) a bug in grails.

Comment: +1 for my shock.  Even if you don't consider it a bug I would like to see the grails documentation mention possible repercussions for not following the convention.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out soon after